# How to make proper unit-test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have method:

```
public ReportBuilder addDiffs(List<String> diffs) {
    if (this.diffs == null) {
        this.diffs = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.diffs.addAll(diffs);
    return this;
}
```

And I want to make unit-test. As I khow it should be like:

```
@Test
public void ReportBuilderTest() {
    ReportBuilder builder = new ReportBuilder();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("some string");

    builder.addDiffs(list);

    assertEquals(builder.getDiffs(), list));
}
```

It is example, but my class is inner service and i can't create getter for it. And diffs are private. How to make proper unit-test for this method? Maybe there is a problem with architecture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

Comment: I suppose it similar question, but as I khow using reflection in unit testing is very bad idea

Comment: See the second answer.

Comment: Unittests verify desired *public observable behavior*, not code, where "public observable behavior" is *return values* and *communication with dependencies*.
Your  method  is expected to change the objects *internal state*. There is no  *public observable behavior* to verify.  
Your code under test (CUT) should have other methods which change their behavior based on the objects state changed via this method.   
E.g.: There must be a method that somehow converts  the list of "diffs" into something being returned by another method or passed to a *dependency* as Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mockito framework. 
The object you are going to use can be built with dummy values using @mock Annotation.
For more information on the different annotations, check the website https://site.mockito.org/

Comment: I know about mockito, but in this case impossible to make mock of the list

Comment: •I'm not very much clear about the question. As per the code snippet provided, 
 the arch should contain the ReportBuilder class as a 'Model', only then you can access its getter and setter methods.
•If you want to check if the values are same then use 
 Assertions.assertThat(builder.getDiffs()).containsExactly("sone string");
• if you want to check the length use  assertEquals(builder.getDiffs().size, list.size));